# The ViewData item that has the key 'CategoryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So my code was working before. I don't know what I did for this to happen and I can't seem to fix it. I've seen people say to reset the ModelState. ( ModelState.Clear(); ) But that didn't help. Also, it doesn't help that I'm still fairly new to MVC. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ActiveDirectoryModel adm = new ActiveDirectoryModel();
        ViewBag.notifyto = adm.FetchContacts();
        var model = Populate();


        return View(model);
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.leaf.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
            model.leaf.Category = model.CategoryId;
            model.leaf.SubCategory = model.SubCategoryId;
            model.leaf.AssignedTo = model.AssignedToId;
            model.leaf.CoAssignedTo = model.CoAssignedToId;
            model.leaf.Status = model.StatusId;
            model.leaf.Priority = model.PriorityId;
            //model.lead.Parent = model.ParentID;

            db.LeafItems.AddObject(model.leaf);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    public CreateViewModel Populate()
    {
        ActiveDirectoryModel adm = new ActiveDirectoryModel();
        var model = new CreateViewModel
        {
            AssignedToItems = adm.FetchContacts(),
            CoAssignedToItems = adm.FetchContacts(),
            NotifyToItems = adm.FetchContacts(),
            CategoryItems =
                from c in new IntraEntities().CategoryItems.ToList()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.Name,
                    Value = c.ID.ToString()
                },
            SubCategoryItems =
                from sc in new IntraEntities().SubCategoryItems.ToList()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = sc.Name,
                    Value = sc.ID.ToString()
                },
            StatusItems =
                from s in new IntraEntities().StatusItems.ToList()
                where s.IsPriority == false
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = s.Name,
                    Value = s.ID.ToString()
                },
            PriorityItems =
                from p in new IntraEntities().StatusItems.ToList()
                where p.IsPriority == true
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = p.Name,
                    Value = p.ID.ToString()
                }
        };
        return model;
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="createTopInner">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.leaf.Category)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoryItems, "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.leaf.Category)
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by running my populate method if the ModelState.IsValid = false.
Once 8 hours passes I can post this as a real answer. I just don't want anyone wasting their time until then.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If your ModelState is not valid on your POST action, you need to repopulate your SelectList properties:

```
if( ModelState.IsValid ) 
{
    // save and redirect
    // ...
}

// repopulate your SelectList properties:
model.CategoryItems = GetCategories();

return View(model);
```

Do not repopulate the entire model because otherwise you could potentially lose any changes that the user made.

Comment: Thanks. It's retaining the values still. But your solution is obviously the safer route.

Comment: @Dismissile can you provide some more information regarding it. Why we need to repopulate select list and is there any side-effect of it. Thanks

Comment: @AvneeshSrivastava MVC is stateless. When you do a POST it's going to re-render the entire view and all the data you had before that isn't getting sent in the POST will be lost. When you submit the form you are only submitted the selected value, not the entire list of items. You need to repopulate it so that it has the full list again.

Answer (score 0):

another way i have find the solution is take hidden field. so in your case you could do as below:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)
```

Now with another field form also post and set CategoryId in respective model.